# Error with import pandas

Tags: python

I'm using Python, and just start importing pandas, then the terminal reports failure like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/L30607/PycharmProjects/untitled1/pandas.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
```

Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed `pandas`, then your local `pandas.py` is shadowing the `pandas` library. To get the original pandas, do:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import pandas as pd
```

Or save the trouble and just rename your own script to something else: `my_pandas.py`.

Comment: or just rename the file itself to something other then `pandas.py`.

Comment: I already tried renaming the script and it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: @m1995 Do you have `pandas` installed, and can you show the traceback of the error you're currently getting?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye i uninstalled and installed it back. now it works